# In-App Bluetooth Pairing Behaviour

Tags: ios, bluetooth, external-accessory, mfi

Unless and Until the Device is paired for the Very first time in the Device settings, they are not show in the Application.And the Bluetooth picker only shows these Paired devices. But as per the docs the behaviour is not as such. Can i Scan for all devices and make the pairing in
the application itself?

```
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:nil completion:^(NSError *error) {}
```

Here the Option 'nil' is specified to search all such devices and also have included the necessary 'supported external accessory protocol' in the info.plist

Is the Behaviour as such or is there something else that i need to do to make it work?

Comment: Hi,
Did you solved this problem?